# React element.scrollHeight in componentDidMount is wrong

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to get the scrollHeight of an element to add a padding to the bottom if it's higher than the offsetHeight but I get in both cases the same value like if the element has not rendered completely or something.

This is how i set it up:

```
componentDidMount(){
    this.checkHeight();
}
componentDidUpdate() {
    this.checkHeight();
}

checkHeight = () => {
    if(this.section){
        window.section = this.section;
        console.log(this.section.offsetHeight, this.section.scrollHeight, ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.section).scrollHeight);
    }
};

render() {
    return (
        <section className={classes.Admin}>
            <ul className={classes.Navbar}>
                <NavbarItem link="/admin" exact clicked={this.changeSectionHandler}>Main</NavbarItem>
                <NavbarItem link={this.props.match.url + '/users'} clicked={this.changeSectionHandler}>Users</NavbarItem>
            </ul>
            <div className={classes.Section} ref={section => this.section = section}>
                <Switch>
                    <Route path={this.props.match.url} exact component={Main}/>
                    <Route path={this.props.match.url + '/users'} exact component={Users}/>
                    <Route path={this.props.match.url + '/users/:id'} exact component={Users}/>
                    <Route path={this.props.match.url + '/users/add'} exact component={Users}/>
                    <Redirect to="/admin"/>
                </Switch>
            </div>
        </section>
    );
}
```

If i get the values of section.offsetHeight and section.scrollHeight in the console after i loaded the page, they are correct.

I'm definitely stuck here, I learned that componentDidMount get fired only when inner components are mounted but I don't know about componentDidUpdate so I guess the problem is there (when I open the scrollable page the componentDidUpdate function is fired, the componentDidMount is useless for the time being).

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm in the exact same boat.

Answer (score 4):

I think it's because when React events fire, actual onscreen rendering is not quite finished (it's not that I'm stating it, it's only my suggestion).

Try to do

```
componentDidMount(){
    setTimeout(this.checkHeight, 0);
}

componentDidUpdate(){
    setTimeout(this.checkHeight, 0);
}
```